# se muestran datos duplicados en mysql

Tags: mysql

Buen día a todos, tengo una base de datos con distintas tablas y estoy tratando de hacer esta consulta:

```
SELECT ta.titulo,ta.fecha_creacion, cu.nombre_curso, ma.nombre_materia, es.nombre_estado 
from tareas AS ta, estado AS es, cursos as cu, materias as ma, materia_profesor as mp, profesor as pr 
where ta.id_estado = es.id_estado 
and mp.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
and ta.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
and ta.id_materia = ma.id_materia 
and mp.id_profesor = pr.id_profesor 
and mp.id_materia = ma.id_materia 
and mp.id_profesor = 1
```

efectivamente me arroja los datos que quiero, pero me los muestra duplicados y aun no logro entender porque.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien sabe me podría indicar porque por favor, de antemano gracias.

estas son las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca la estructura de las tablas con sus respectivas relaciones, esto te ayudará a conseguir una mayor chance de una buena respuesta :D

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Excelente, solo una petición ¿podrías poner código en lugar de imágenes por favor? Es más sencillo copiar y pegar para reproducir tu escenario :)

Comment: ok.. a ver. tratemos de ordenar.. lo que pasa aca es que en todas las relaciones que estas haciendo, una duplica registros.. si vas agregando las tablas de a una no te va a pasar.. pero, de otra forma, pone la estructura como codigo, datos de ejemplo y saca todo lo que no sea necesario

Comment: lo siento, la pregunta no me permite poner tanto código, por eso lo puse como imagenes.

Comment: Solo hay 7 campos en tu select (mas los de join), saca todo lo que no sea necesario y deja solo lo que sirva para la pregunta...

Comment: ya edite la pregunta nuevamente, eliminé los campos del select que no eran necesarios, pero lo del where en adelante si es necesario .

Answer (score -1):

¿ya intententaste poner INNER JOIN para no poner tantos Where y nombre de tablas en el FROM?

Puede que traiga un registro por cada condición (AND) que pusiste.

Comment: Sintacticamente, esto no contesta a la pregunta, porque si el where esta correcto, funciona exactamente igual...